# Rails admin custom action on model index only to some models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I want to add a custom action for a specific model called Loan.

I want to have a button on the model index for this action, I don't want a view for this, just a button on the list of models.

Also, I need to put this action on the model index only on same models. Let's say, the Loans that have `status == some_status`.

How do I do all this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please share what you have thus far?

Comment: I have edited with more info on what I need

Comment: Take a look at the documentation on how to create a custom action.
https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Custom-action

Answer (score -1):

From a very high level you just need to branch on your condition. We have a bunch of ways to do that, but the simplest is probably something like this:

#### loans/index.html.erb

```
<% @loans.each do |loan| %>
  <td>loan.name</td>
  <td>loan.rate</td>
  <td>
  <% if loan.status == some_status %>
    <!-- button code here -->
  <% end %>
  </td>
<% end %>
```

If the loan status equals the value for `some_status` the button will be displayed. Otherwise that cell would be left empty.

Comment: I don't understand how this modifies the rails admin view

Comment: The question doesn't reference an admin view, only the index. The principle concept is the same no matter what view you are editing. Lines 5-7 in my example above do what you're asking. If you need more specific help, you would have to post your existing code.